# What is the static method positioninArea used for in JavaFX LineChart?

Tags: java, javafx

The line chart in `JavaFX` has a static method called `positioninArea` - here is the doc:

*positionInArea(Node child, double areaX, double areaY, double areaWidth, double areaHeight, double areaBaselineOffset, Insets margin, HPos halignment, VPos valignment, boolean isSnapToPixel)*

*Utility method which positions the child within an area of this region defined by areaX, areaY, areaWidth x areaHeight, with a baseline offset relative to that area.*

What is this method used for? I do not understand the explanation. Can I add a node i.e.: a rectangle inside the chart using this method? For example:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(35, 35, 35, 35);
rec.setFill(Color.RED);
lineChart.positionInArea(rec, 50, 50, 35, 35, 10, new Insets(0), HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER, true);
```

I tried this but the rectangle does not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `positionInArea` method is not defined on `LineChart`, but by `Region`. It is primarily used to help position the children of the `Region` when overriding the `layoutChildren` method. It does this by modifying the various layout properties of the `Node`.

Your `Rectangle` is not added to the scene-graph, let alone a child of the `LineChart`. Calling `positionInArea` with the `Rectangle` will have no visual effect. The method doesn't add the `Node` to the children list, it just sets some properties on the `Rectangle`.